# How to check Installed Fonts on Android Device

Tags: java, android, android-layout

we want to check android devices installed fonts, can we check it in android Java & can install any font there

Comment: Could you please check your spelling? It is very hard to understand what you really want or need... or just try to explain your problem further.

Answer (score 4):

There are only three system wide fonts in Android; normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif), and monospace (Droid Sans Mono).

Applications can install fonts for themselves, but not for system-wide use.

To package your own font, include a truetype font file (.ttf) as an asset and use the [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) class to load it, and the [setTypeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface,%20int%29) method of TextView to use it.

Comment: I am trying to set arabic font but it's looking not setting exact my font.

Answer (score 1):

To use a special font create a normal TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_font"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the Chantelli Antiqua font."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then set a custom Typeface from an asset (this is your desired font):

```
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

The code is from: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

I hope I could help.